# Django 1.10 NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django

I have a trouble, just read themes which correspondent to the trouble, but don't found the solution. I am new with Django, try to create base shablon of the site, due to manual. My base.html file

```
<p>  <a href="{% url '_my_alfanet_:index' %}">My AlfaNet Portal</a> </p>
 >{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

My index.html file:

```
{% extends "_my_alfanet_/base.html" %}
{% block content %} <p>My AlfabankNet Portal allows you to extract information about the nets and devices of MyAlfaBank Net.</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

My project urls.py file

```
 """Определяет схемы URL для My AlfaNet."""
from django.conf.urls import url
from _my_alfanet_ import views
urlpatterns = [  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'', include('_my_alfanet_.urls', namespace='_my_alfanet_')),
]
```

My project views.py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.contrib import admin

def index(request):
  """Домашняя страница приложения Learning Log"""
  return render(request, '_my_alfanet_/index.html')
```

Result after all of this was done:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
u'_my_alfanet_' is not a registered namespace
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://172.17.45.9:8002/
Django Version: 1.10.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
u'_my_alfanet_' is not a registered namespace
Exception Location: /etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py in reverse, line 87
Python Executable:  /etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['/etc/network/scripts',
 '/etc/network/scripts/ansible/lib',
 '/etc/network/scripts',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python27.zip',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 9 Mar 2017 13:25:44 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template /etc/network/scripts/_my_alfanet_/templates/_my_alfanet_/index.html, error at line 0
u'_my_alfanet_' is not a registered namespace
1   {% extends "_my_alfanet_/base.html" %}
2   {% block content %} <p>My AlfabankNet Portal allows you to extract information about the nets and devices of MyAlfaBank Net.</p> 
3   {% endblock content %}
```

Whats wrong with this? I tried to include name space everywhere where needed, but noone good result. Could someone help with this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using leading and trailing underscores to name things? That may or may not be related to your problem, but it's definitely unconventional.

Comment: Maybe it is not very good, but index.html without base.html worked fine. So it is really not a cause.  It is test project, finally it will be another names, I think

Comment: Your folder name doesn't have to match the namespace, it might be worth removing the underscores for the namespace to see if that is the issue

Comment: Ok, this done, now I have an error

`u'my_alfanets' is not a registered namespace` 

So it was not the case

Comment: If the above error comes with `url(r'', include('_my_alfanet_.urls', namespace='my_alfanet')),` then your project is not getting the urls config file. Also, could you add contents of `_my_alfanet_/urls.py`?

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 """Определяет схемы URL для My AlfaNet."""
from django.conf.urls import url
from my_alfanets import views
urlpatterns = [  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'', include('my_alfanets.urls', namespace='my_alfanets')),
]`


**_my_alfanet_**  became  **my_alfanets**. Error is the same

Comment: I found the problem: I replace urls.py by each other (urls.py from different locations, from project and in main directory) and all began to work. They where jumble.